# Search/replace loop goes awry

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-formatting

We have a course schedule, that looks like the following (first 4 rows) in Eastern Time.

```
Sat 12/08/2012  1:00-3:30 PM
Mon 12/10/2012  9:30-12:00 AM
Wed 12/12/2012  9:30-12:00 AM
Sat 12/15/2012  1:00-3:30 PM
```

You can check a radio button and pick a different time zone. For example, if you pick Central Time, you should see this on change:

```
Sat 12/08/2012  12:00-2:30 PM
Mon 12/10/2012  8:30-11:00 AM
Wed 12/12/2012  8:30-11:00 AM
Sat 12/15/2012  12:00-2:30 PM
```

Instead you see:

```
Wed 30/05/2012  8:09 am-11:09 pm
Sat 00/08/2012  12:09-2:09 pm
Mon 30/10/2012  8:09 am-11:09 pm
Wed 30/12/2012  8:09 am-11:09 pm
```

Part of this may be a date format issue, but the format works correctly elsewhere. I think the main problem is in the change loop (each), which grabs the three pieces of each row (0=the day, 1=date, 2=time (which is actually split into a subarray of 0 and 1 for start and end times, and there is a special case for midnight)) applies the timeshift for the new time zone, and builds new row content. I can't find what is going wrong. Any ideas appreciated. (init vars and other top stuff omitted):

```
$('.timezoneSel').click(function (evtObj) {
    _curevtObj = evtObj;
    _prevtmzObj = _curtmzObj;
    $('input.timezoneSel[value="' + _curevtObj.target.value + '"]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });
    for (var x = 0; x < timezoneset.length; x++) if (timezoneset[x].abbr == _curevtObj.target.value) _curtmzObj = timezoneset[x];
    $('table.TPR_tblcoursedetails').each(function (i, val) {
        $(this).contents().find('tr').each(function (irow, vrow) {
            isEvening = false;
            $(this).contents().find('span').each(function (icol, vcol) {
                switch (icol) {
                    case 0:
                        rowwday = vcol.innerHTML;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        rowdate = vcol.innerHTML;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        rowtime = vcol.innerHTML;
                        break;
                }
            });
            isEvening = ((rowtime.indexOf(" PM") > -1) ? true : false);
            rowtimearr = rowtime.split("-");
            if (rowtimearr[0] == MidNiteStr) rowtimearr[0] = "12:00 AM";
            if (rowtimearr[1] == MidNiteStr) rowtimearr[1] = "12:00 AM";
            if (rowtimearr[0].indexOf(" AM") < 0 && rowtimearr[0].indexOf(" PM") < 0) rowtimearr[0] += isEvening ? " PM" : " AM";
            newStartDate = new Date(rowdate + ' ' + rowtimearr[0]);
            newEndDate = new Date(rowdate + ' ' + rowtimearr[1]);
            newStartDateMsec = newStartDate.getTime() + ((_curtmzObj.offset - _prevtmzObj.offset) * msecPerHour);
            newEndDateMsec = newEndDate.getTime() + ((_curtmzObj.offset - _prevtmzObj.offset) * msecPerHour);
            newStartDate = new Date(newStartDateMsec);
            console.log(newStartDate);
            newEndDate = new Date(newEndDateMsec);
            $(this).contents().find('span').each(function (icol2, vcol2) {
                adjStartTimeTT = newStartDate.format('tt');
                adjEndTimeTT = newEndDate.format('tt');
                console.log(adjStartTimeTT, adjEndTimeTT);
                switch (icol2) {
                    case 0:
                        vcol2.innerHTML = newStartDate.format("ddd");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        vcol2.innerHTML = newStartDate.format("MM/dd/yyyy");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        vcol2.innerHTML = ((adjStartTimeTT == adjEndTimeTT) ? newStartDate.format("h:mm") : newStartDate.format("h:mm tt")) + "-" + ((useMidNite && newEndDate.format("h:mm tt") == "12:00 AM") ? MidNiteStr : newEndDate.format("h:mm tt"));
                        break;
                }
            });
        });
        filledonce = false;
    });
```

Comment: I would only suggest to refactor this code: extract the code that calculates the timezones from the UI code (jQuery/HTML). Then it will be easier to understand, fix and test this code. Otherwise you'll need to find a really skilled (or bored?) person to help you with this.

Comment: Thank you, although the issue is really the intersection of both. Maybe.

Comment: Hey, you've got a date formatting library included! Which one is it? Maybe you could make more use of it.

Comment: Well, that's a side thing, but this code is inside EktronCMS400 and JS date format syntax seems to be slightly diff than used by ASP.NET-very annoying--have to look into that later.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turns out this line:

```
$('.TPR_tblcoursedetails').html($('.TPR_tblcoursedetails').html().replace(/ EST/g, ""));
```

which is above the main loop, was not looping itself. It was just grabbing the EST once and replacing it throughout, but it also it made the big loop below it do the same thing, so the interation was not correct. We changed this to:

```
$('.TPR_tblcoursedetails').each(function(iobj,vobj){
                vobj.innerHTML.replace(/ EST/g, "");
            });
```